# Car just Quit on road.

Tags: honda, accord, cranks-wont-run

Will turn over but not start. No water or oil leaking and belts are tight. What's wrong?? Honda Accord EX. '98. It has oil n water full,  all belts (2) are still on n tight. Just quit on road.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried to get the codes read?

Comment: Are you sure the fuel gauge is working? What is the status of the battery?

Comment: Have you checked for spark?

Comment: Was there an unusual noise just before it quit? Could be timing belt that snapped. What engine is it (I4 or V6)?